# How can I get list of words between two special charecters

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Input

```
text {{123}}text{{hello}} text {{ john }} text{{ wick }}text
```

Desired Output

```
123 hello john wick
```

I tried

```
sed 's/.*{{\(.*\)}}.*/\1/' <<< "$s"
```

which gives me only last value `wick`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `gnu awk`:

```
s='text {{123}}text{{hello}} text {{ john }} text{{ wick }}text'
awk -v FPAT='{{[^}]*}}' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(/^{{[ \t]*|[ \t]*}}$/, "", $i)
      printf "%s", $i (i < NF ? OFS : ORS)
   }
}' <<< "$s"
```

```
123 hello john wick
```

Answer (score 1):

If GNU awk is also possible:

```
awk '{$1=$1; gsub("({{ *| *}})","",$0)}1' FPAT='{{ *[^}]* *}}' file
```

Output:

```
123 hello john wick
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
perl -lne 'print join " ", /\{\{\h*\K.*?(?=\h*\}\})/g'
```

- `/\{\{\h*\K.*?(?=\h*\}\})/g` to get all matches that are found between `{{` and `}}` with optional horizontal spaces around the match

  - `.*?` is non-greedy, `.*` is greedy and will match from first `{{` to last `}}`
  - `\K` to ignore matching text before this point
  - `(?=...)` is lookahead, again to avoid this portion as part of matched text
- the matches are then joined with space as separator

With `sed`

```
sed 's/[^{]*{{ *\([^} ]*\) *}}[^{]*/\1 /g; s/ *$//'
```

This works for given sample, but may not suit for other cases. This works by deleting text around the required portions, assuming `{` and `}` are unique enough.

Answer (score 0):

> - `upside`   :: entirely bypassing  capturing groups
> - `downside` :: *extra spaces between some of the words, since it delineates by double pairs of curly brackets while retaining all spaces within it*

---

```
mawk NF=NF FS='(^|[}]+)[^{]*([{]+|$)'
```

---

```
 123 hello  john   wick
```

to quickly extract out the components, in general, try

```
gawk NF=NF FS=' *[{}]+ *' OFS='\14\10\10'
```

---

```
text
  123
   text
     hello
        text
          john
            text
              wick
                text
```